# d3.js circles don't show after trying to use the update pattern

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Me again - perhaps there is some day i'm the one helping. But at the moment i'm totally lost. (i'm absolutely new to d3.js and my javascript knowledge is very basic at the moment)

So... i'm trying to make an interactive visualization of Charakter and their relation. The plan ist to start with one Character (the one who is logged in) and to show his relations at first. When the user now is clicking on his node, the magic should happen and the relations of the clicked node shoul appear... and so on. (in the progress the user should also be able to hide nodes again but baby steps... :D )

So i loaded the code and my json files to git hub, you can find it here:
https://github.com/katjalennartz/ba (index2.html should show everything the js code is in noForce2.js)

I'm pretty sure the problem that no circle is shown depends on my groups, and that there i messed up everything. I'm not sure how to bind my data correctly, so that it's possible to drag the nodes (and so that the links and text follows the nodes...)

This is the part i'm  pretty sure, which is not working:

```
        .selectAll("circles") // was null before try to use an update function -> null for save index 0 from missing when append circles. but null now is not working
            .data(rootNodes)
  
        //Exit (remove old elements)
        circleGroup.exit().remove;
        
        //Enter data 
        circleGroup.enter()
            .append('g')
            .attr('transform', function (d) {
                return 'translate(' + d.x + ',' + d.y + ')'; //work not nested data
            })
            .call(d3.drag() //need the drag so you can play with the nodes - links should follow - try to group it for show text beside circle
                .on("start", dragstarted)
                .on("drag", dragged)
                .on("end", dragended));
        
        //add the circle 
        circleGroup.append("circle")
            .attr("r", function (d) {
                //increase radius if current user 
                if (d.id === thisuser) {
                    return radius * 2
                } else { return radius; }
            })
            .attr("class", "chara")
            .attr("fill", function (d) {
                //set color to red if current user 
                return (d.id === thisuser) ? "red" : "blue"
            })
            .style("stroke", "#ffffff")
            .on("click", update); //this should call the update
        
        //set text to circle (username)
        circleGroup.append("text")
            .text(function (d, i) { return d.username; })
            //.style('text-anchor', 'top')
            .attr("x", radius)
            .attr("y", 4);
```

perhaps someone here could help me clear that mess, i would be totally thankful

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the reference to `circleGroup`. When you first use `circleGroup`, here's what you do:

```
var circleGroup = svg
    .selectAll("g") 
    .data(rootNodes)
```

Right now `circleGroup` is the `update` selection. It's when using either `enter()` or `exit()` that it becomes the enter selection you want. This is done properly here:

```
circleGroup.enter() // Enter selection
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', function (d) {
        return 'translate(' + d.x + ',' + d.y + ')';
    })
    .call(d3.drag() 
        .on("start", dragstarted)
        .on("drag", dragged)
        .on("end", dragended));
```

but not here:

```
circleGroup.append("circle") // no enter(), so update selection
    .attr("r", function (d) {
        if (d.id === thisuser) {
            return radius * 2
        } else { return radius; }
    })
    .attr("class", "chara")
    .attr("fill", function (d) {
        return (d.id === thisuser) ? "red" : "blue"
    })
    .style("stroke", "#ffffff")
    .on("click", update);
```

What you can do is use the enter() in the circleGroup variable directly, making it represent the enter selection. If you need to use the update and exit selection too, use another variable:

```
var circleGroup = svg
    .selectAll("g") 
    .data(rootNodes) // update

var circleGroupEnter = circleGroup.enter()

circleGroupEnter
    .append("circle")
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', function (d) {
        return 'translate(' + d.x + ',' + d.y + ')'; //work not nested data
    })
    .call(d3.drag() //need the drag so you can play with the nodes - links should follow - try to group it for show text beside circle
        .on("start", dragstarted)
        .on("drag", dragged)
        .on("end", dragended));

        
circleGroupEnter
    .attr("r", function (d) {
        if (d.id === thisuser) {
            return radius * 2
        } else { return radius; }
    })
    .attr("class", "chara")
    .attr("fill", function (d) {
        return (d.id === thisuser) ? "red" : "blue"
    })
    .style("stroke", "#ffffff")
    .on("click", update);
```

## Using `selection.join()`

The above is a bit heavy handed. You can use `selection.join()` to simplify - to understand how it works, [see this tutorial](https://observablehq.com/@d3/learn-d3-joins?collection=@d3/learn-d3).

```
var circleGroup = svg
    .selectAll("g") 
    .data(rootNodes)

circleGroup
    .join('g')
    .attr('transform', function (d) {
        return 'translate(' + d.x + ',' + d.y + ')';
    })
    .call(d3.drag() 
        .on("start", dragstarted)
        .on("drag", dragged)
        .on("end", dragended));

        
circleGroup
    .join("circle")
    .attr("r", function (d) {
        if (d.id === thisuser) {
            return radius * 2
        } else { return radius; }
    })
    .attr("class", "chara")
    .attr("fill", function (d) {
        return (d.id === thisuser) ? "red" : "blue"
    })
    .style("stroke", "#ffffff")
    .on("click", update);
```

`selection.join()` also works for handling the three selections: here's an example from later in your code:

```
var link = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(rootLinks);
        
link.join(
    enter => enter.append('line'),
    update => update,
    exit => exit.remove()
)
```

Comment: wow! thanks a lot. You really, really helped me. And thanks a lot for the explanation! 

Now i get my nodes and the new ones, when i'm clicking on one. Also i get my lines, but heres my next problem. 

I don't now hot to make my lines, 'following' the nodes, when the nodes are dragged. Do you have an idea, how to solve this? 
I updates my github (https://github.com/katjalennartz/ba), version 2c now is the 'working' file. index2.html should show it.